# How to sort 2D dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I am having trouble sorting a 2D dynamic struct array.

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct abc
{
    int total;
} abc;
```

And a dynamic 2D array:

```
list = (abc**)malloc(listSize * sizeof(abc*));
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        list[i] = (abc*)malloc(listSize2* sizeof(abc));
    }
```

I want to use a sorting algorithm:

```
qsort(list, listSize, sizeof list[0], cmp);
```

and the compare function for the qsort:

```
int cmp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const abc *a = *(const abc **)l;
    const abc *b = *(const abc **)r;

    return a[0].total > b[0].total;

}
```

But the problem is that although I think it works for a small list (like about 5 ints), it fails to sort properly if the list is a bit bigger. What should I do to the cmp() function so it works properly?

By the way, I only need to sort `list[x][0]` since I will be adding more elements later.

[(I'm basing my sorting code from another Stackoverflow post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202178/c-qsort-with-dynamic-n-by-2-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: See [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the compare function to:

```
int cmp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const abc *a = *(const abc **)l;
    const abc *b = *(const abc **)r;

    return a[0].total - b[0].total;

}
```

Using `qsort` the expected compare function should return negative if first value is smaller positive if it is bigger and 0 if the two values are equal.

EDIT: thanks to WhozCraig: if you think you may hit under or overflow you may go for a safer version:

```
int cmp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const abc *a = *(const abc **)l;
    const abc *b = *(const abc **)r;

    if (a[0].total < b[0].total) {
       return -1;
    } else if (a[0].total > b[0].total) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing problematic with this is if `a[0].total` is already a negative number and `b[0].total is a very large *positive* number. The subtraction method is subject to underflow (or overflow if the signs are reversed).

Comment: Yeah, that would do it. You can also get away with `return (a < b) ? -1 : (b < a);`. (oh, and +1)

Comment: The first one gives me a Segmentation Fault but the second one works! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

With the following structure:

```
typedef struct abc {
    int total;
} ABC;
```

Compare function can be simple as:

```
int cmp(const void *l, const void *r)
{
    const ABC *a = (const ABC *) l;
    const ABC *b = (const ABC *) r;
    if (a->total == b->total) return 0;
    return (a->total < b->total) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

used for example like:

```
ABC list[][4]  = {{{5},{2},{0},{4}},
                  {{7},{3},{9},{1}},
                  {{8},{6},{5},{7}},
                  {{2},{7},{9},{5}}};

qsort(list, 4 * 4, sizeof(ABC), cmp);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        printf("%d ",list[i][j].total);
```

which outputs: `0 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 8 9 9`.

And in case you want to sort it within rows only, you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)                 
    qsort(list[i], 4, sizeof(ABC), cmp);
```

which would give you: `0 2 4 5 1 3 7 9 5 6 7 8 2 5 7 9`. In this case (sorting within rows), it doesn't matter whether the `list` as whole is stored within the single block of memory or not. Neither it matters if it has been allocated dynamically or not :)

Comment: in c's qsort the compare function is not boolean it returns a negtive value, positive value or 0.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Yes. Thanks, I fixed it. Although the previous version somehow worked too.

Comment: @LihO I saw your code before you edited after Ivaylo Strandjev's comment and the code did attempt to sort it but the list was still a mess. The code after the edit doesn't seem to work for some reason. Gives me a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @StarShire: I had there one more typo while sorting within rows, I was passing `list[0]` instead of `list[i]`, you might check edit log.